# from where i can get username and password for SSH login?

Tags: ssh

My client asked me to do a ssh login. But i haven't done any ssh login before. So can you please suggest me how to do ssh login. I am using putty on windows.
now putty asks username and password.what should i enter there.cpanel login details? from where i can get these information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Login is  the **"username@ipaddress"** of the remote computer.It prompts for password automatically when you connect. This username and password are system wide basically.For more specific details about enabling ssh in cPanel and connecting refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yx1gZKgb5Y).

Comment: thank you..this video helped me. but i have watched some youtube videos.they just add username and,password. didnt say which username and which password

Comment: That username and password should be known to you or get them from your client.As shown in the video ssh should be enabled on cPanel.The official [link](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/SSH+Access) documentation guides you how to enable on cPanel.

Comment: ok..i am scared to ask anything from my client .because then he will know i have know any experience.that's why ask it here :)